# Primary Key for one table with two columns, which have multilple dupilicated values

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-relationship

i have a table with 3 columns

**Table_1**

```
Timestamp                       Station        Value
2022-08-09T11:15:00+02:00       A              12
2022-08-09T11:30:00+02:00       A              15
.....
2022-08-09T11:15:00+02:00       X              29
2022-08-09T11:30:00+02:00       X              40
```

So the Timestamp are pretty the same (the station recorded the values each 15 Minutes)

And the second Table is like this

**Table_2**

```
Number_id     Station
234562        A
452365        B
.....
352364        X
```

I am really confused about Primary key in **Table_1**, which Column in **Table_1** should be Primary Key?

And should the Column "Station" in **Table_1** be the Foreign Key from **Table_2**?

Or i should change the dimension of the **Table_1**? Problem is, there is so much timestamp (in example i just choosed 2 of them, in my real table, there are many more, because this is timestamp of 7 days)

Anyone can give me a suggestion?

Comment: table2 is the boss and should have a unique or primary key on station, table 1 should have an fk on station which should reference table2.There is no requirement for tables to have a primary key but it would be useful if table1 had an an auto_increment id as the primary key. Any other keys on table1 would be indicated by the kind of queries you intend to carry out. NB I have no idea what function number_id in table2 might fulfil.

Comment: thank you for your suggetion, i think the auto_increment_id might be a good for table_1. The number_id is for other purpose, because there are still other tables, i just take the important columns from each table to make it easier to understand!

Comment: In that case it might be more consistent to use number_id in table1 in preference to station